# Suppose that $A$ is a $5\times 3$ matrix and there exists....

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, inverse

Suppose that $A$ is a $5\times 3$ matrix and there exists a $3\times 5$ matrix $C$ such that $C$$A$ = $I$. Suppose further that for some $b$ in $R^5$, $Ax = b$ has at least one solution. Show that this solution is unique.

Down below is my attempt at solving this, and I need someone to check my work by giving me hints.

If there exists a matrix $C$ such that $C$$A$ = $I$, then we know that the matrix is invertible.

If the matrix is invertible, then $Ax = b$ has a unique solution for ALL $b$, this implies that the $b$ in $\Bbb R^5$ MUST be unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to rephrase the problem in terms of linear maps:

$A:\mathbb R^5 \to \mathbb R^3$ and $C:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^5$.

If $CA=I$, with $I$ the identity map on $\mathbb R^5$, then $A$ must be injective.

[This is a property of functions in general.](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Injection_iff_Left_Inverse)

Comment: I think i might need another hint here.. im still stuck

Comment: This actually stands as basically a full proof. What is your confusion?

Comment: I just have a quick question about injective transformations. If $Ax = b$ is injective, then does that mean that every $b$ is either a unique solution or not a solution?

Comment: @Soon_to_be_code_master indeed :)

Comment: I have another question, if the product of two matrices is the identity matrix, then does that mean that the two matrices are injective?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Assume that there is more than one solution, say $x$ and $y$ are solutions, and compute $$CA(x-y)$$
in two ways.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is wrong. For a matrix to be invertible, it must be square. If it *is* square and a matrix $C$ with $CA = I$ exists, then it turns out that $A$ is invertible. But if it's not square...then it doesn't make sense to say it's invertible, and you need a rather different argument.